# How can I add a legend to a mayavi plot

Tags: python, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I can't seem to get a legend to appear on a mayavi plot. I have created a simple 3d plot but I need to provide a legend for the plot. Matplotlib supports adding by:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, y, z, label="my-label")
```

I didn't find any working examples of such legends in mayavi.

Comment: a long shot would be to use `mlab.text()`, see [the Wigner example](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_wigner.html#example-wigner)

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the method in my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Since mayavi doesn't have a built in method for creating legends the easiest way to do this would be to create your mavavi figure and then read it into matplotlib and make a legend. This requires you to have programmatic access to the color values used in creating the mayavi plot - it is much easier when you specify the colors explicitly instead of letting the color cycler automatically assign colors.

Here is an example which creates a mayavi figure and then passes it to matplotlib to then create a legend.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import mayavi.mlab as mlab
from mayavi.api import OffScreenEngine
import numpy as np

mlab.options.offscreen = True
e = OffScreenEngine()
e.start()
fig = mlab.figure(engine=e, size=(5000,5000), fgcolor=(0,0,0), bgcolor=(1,1,1))
mlab.view(azimuth=45, elevation=0)

n = 500
d = np.linspace(0, np.pi*8, n)

mlab.plot3d(d, np.cos(d**1.2), np.cos(d), color = colors[0])
mlab.plot3d(d, np.sin(d), np.sin(d), color = colors[1])
mlab.plot3d(d, np.sin(d)*np.cos(d), np.cos(d), color = colors[2])
mlab.plot3d(d, np.sin(d)**2, np.sin(d)**2, color = colors[3])

mlab.savefig("./example.png")

im = plt.imread("./example.png")
labels = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]

elements = [Line2D([0], [0], label = l, color = c) for l, c in zip(labels, colors[:4])]
plt.imshow(im)
plt.legend(handles = elements)
plt.gca().set_axis_off()
plt.subplots_adjust(top = 1, bottom = 0, right = 1, left = 0, 
            hspace = 0, wspace = 0)
plt.margins(0,0)
plt.savefig("./example.png")
```

`colors` is an array of `RGB` values in the range `[0.0, 1.0]`. The example uses the [Tableau 20 color palette](https://public.tableau.com/profile/chris.gerrard#!/vizhome/TableauColors/ColorPaletteswithRGBValues) mapped into the `[0.0, 1.0]` space. This generates the following output

[image]